# Adding three PHP if queries into one page with HTML

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, loops, if-statement

I have three

```
<?php if( array_key_exists( 'overview', $wp_query->query_vars ) ){
;}?>
```

In one `single-post.php` template

```
<?php if( array_key_exists( 'overview', $wp_query->query_vars ) ){
;}?>

<?php if( array_key_exists( 'analytics', $wp_query->query_vars ) ){
;}?>

<?php if( array_key_exists( 'edit', $wp_query->query_vars ) ){
;}?>
```

I need them contain variations of the below

```
<div class="content ">
    <div class="container-fluid bg-transparent m-t-50 container-fixed-lg">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <button onclick="location.href='/campaigns'" class="btn btn-default btn-xs  btn-rounded m-r-20"><i class="fa fa-angle-left" style="color:#828ba4"></i>  <span class="back-campaign">Back to campaigns</span></button>
                <h1>
                    <?php the_title(); ?>   
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 hidden-md-up">
                <div class="pull-left">
                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink() ); ?>/analytics">
                    <button class="m-t-10 m-b-10 btn btn-grey btn-cons"  type="button">
                    View Analytics
                    </button>
                    </a>
                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink() ); ?>/edit-campaign">
                    <button class="m-t-10 m-b-10 btn btn-primary btn-cons"  type="button">
                    Edit Campaign
                    </button>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I believe the solution that I am looking for is to do something similar to the below as I do not want them as an echo

```
<?php if( array_key_exists( 'overview', $wp_query->query_vars ) );?>
<div>HTML Content for overview</div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if( array_key_exists( 'analytics', $wp_query->query_vars ) );?>
<div>HTML Content for analytics</div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if( array_key_exists( 'analytics', $wp_query->query_vars ) );?>
<div>HTML Content for analytics</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

When trying this method I receive a 500 error but this is along the lines of what I am trying to achieve.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: use `<?= ?>` instead of `<?php ?>`

Comment: you could use `print` (not much different from `echo`) or `incude`

Comment: @RJParikh `<?=` is just a shorthand for `echo`

Comment: Thank you for your help. This will allow me to copy the HTML without formatting it for PHP?

Comment: <?= ?> should be avoided. Short tag can be turned off in any server configuration.

Comment: I have updated the question with more about what I am trying to achieve. Hope this helps you understand my question better. If not, please let me know what information you would like.

Comment: Or perhaps the `HTML` could be saved in a separate `PHP` template and `echo file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/template.php");`

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I have posted the solution as an answer know. Appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to create a separate file with the HTML content, saved as `.php`. Then, use `include("file_name.php");` within

```
<?php if( array_key_exists( 'overview', $wp_query->query_vars ) ){;}?>
```

to appear as

```
<?php if( array_key_exists( 'overview', $wp_query->query_vars ) ){
include("single-campaign-overview.php");}?>
```

I did notice a little latency in the page load times but not enough to be a problem.

Comment: I know the better method would have been to convert the HTML to PHP entirely and not use separate files. However, I was looking for a least time-consuming method that would achieve the job. If anyone has a better solution please share.